# Why is my kubernetes readiness probe for hashicorp vault hitting http when I specify https?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, hashicorp-vault

My readiness probe specifies HTTPS and 8200 as the port to check my hashicorp vault pod.

```
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      scheme: HTTPS
      path: '/v1/sys/health?activecode=200'
      port: 8200
```

Once the pod is running kubectl describe pod shows this

```
Readiness probe failed: Error checking seal status: Error making API request.

URL: GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status
Code: 400. Raw Message:

Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

Comment: Hello @MatthewWimpelberg, did provided answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564594/hashicorp-vault-client-sent-an-http-request-to-an-https-server-readiness-pro).  See [the whole answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565711/16739663).

According to [this documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm/configuration):

> The http/https scheme is controlled by the `tlsDisable` value.

> When set to `true`, changes URLs from `https` to `http` (such as the `VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200` environment variable set on the Vault pods).

To turn it off:

```yaml
global:
  tlsDisable: false
```

> **NOTE**:
> Vault should always be [used with TLS](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/listener/tcp#tls_cert_file) in production to provide secure communication between clients and the Vault server. It requires a certificate file and key file on each host where Vault is running.

---

See also [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/). One can find there many examples of using readiness and liveness probes, f.e

```yaml
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -ec
        - vault status
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```